# TypeScript: Cast whole class type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-compiler-api

I am wondering if it is possible to change the type of a class property? But not with a simple cast but rather with overwriting the whole class type.

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class Test {
  public myNumber = 7;
}
```

Is it possible to change the type of the **myNumber** property from **number** to e.g. **string**?

Let's assume that we have a custom typescript transformer in place that transforms every property of type number of a class to a string. Then it would be cool to have this reflected somehow in the development process. That's why I am asking if it is possible to adjust the type.

I am looking for an option to override the whole class type definition without casting each property. E.g. not doing this:

```
const test = new Test();
(
test.myNumber as string).toUpperCase();
```

My first thought would be that this can maybe be achieved with *index types*. But I wanted to ask if someone already  has experience with this or has a concrete idea.

E.g. it would be cool to call a function...

```
whatever(Test)
```

... and after this the type of the class is changed. So the compiler should know from now on that e.g. **myNumber** is supposed to be of type **string** and not **number**.

So this should be possible now:

```
const test = new Test();
test.myNumber.toUpperCase();
```

The meaningfulness of this example is not important. It is just a made up use case to illustrate the problem in a (hopefully) simple way.

===

Because the context (how the class will be consumed) was mentioned in the comments of this issue I would like to additionally provide the following example. It is a test (spec) file of an *Angular* component using *jasmine* and *karma*. I tried to explain myself with the comments in the code snippet.

```
describe('ParentComponent', () => {
  let component: ParentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentComponent>;

  /**
   * This function is the "marker" for the custom typescript transformer.
   * With this line the typescript transformer "knows" that it has to adjust the class ParentComponent.
   *
   * I don't know if this is possible but it would be cool if after the function "ttransformer" the type for ParentComponent would be adjusted.
   * With adjusted I mean that e.g. each class property of type number is now reflected as type string (as explained in the issue description above)
   */
  ttransformer(ParentComponent);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ParentComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('test it', () => {
    // This cast should not be necessary
    (component.ttransformerTest as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue('Transformer Test');
    expect(component.ttransformerTest).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

===

Thanks in advance,
Lukas

Comment: It depends to some extent on how you plan on consuming the class. Like you can apply the type transformation on export, but within the exporting module the language will not be available.

Comment: I added further information at the end of the issue description. Hopefully that helps. Currently I am not quite sure what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

This is sort of a strange pattern, and not something I'd recommend doing lightly, but it is largely achievable:

Instances and Constructors

When you declare your class `Test`, Typescript really makes two things: a type named `Test` which is the instance of a `Test` class, and a value also named `Test` which is a constructor that builds the type `Test`.  While TS is able to give these the same name and bring them into scope together with a single `class` declaration, we'll have to deal with them separately.

Transforming the Instance

So, dealing with the instances, we can write a type that transforms an instance of `Test` with numbers to an instance with strings:

```
type NumbersToStrings<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? string : T[K]
}
type TransformedTest = NumersToStrings<Test>; // Remember, `Test` is the instance not the constructor
```

Transforming the Constructor

Now we'll need to represent a constructor that builds these `TransformedTest` instances.  We could manually write a constructor with arguments that match the constructor for `Test`:

```
type TransformedTestCtor = new(/*constructor arguments*/) => TransformedTest;
```

Or we can write a type that takes a constructor and returns a constructor that takes the same arg but constructs a different instance:

```
type ClassTransform<
  OldClass extends new (...args: any[]) => any,
  NewType
> = OldClass extends new (...args: infer Args) => any
  ? new (...args: Args) => NewType
  : never;

// Test - as a value is the constructor, so `typeof Test` is the type of the constructor
type TransformedTestCtor = ClassTransform<typeof Test, TransformedTest>;
```

Usage

So now we have a constructor that takes the same arguments but returns a different instance.  How can we actually use this?

Unfortunately, syntax like this won't work:

```
whatever(Test)
```

You can normally change the type of a function's argument using `asserts` signature, but it doesn't work on classes.

So, there's not really a better approach than just asserting the type:

```
const TransformedTest = Test as unknown as TransformedTestConstructor;
```

By naming this constructor the same as the instance type we defined earlier, we mimic the usual pattern where a constructor (value) and an instance (type) share the same name.  (And can, e.g. be exported together)

Another option is to put this in a function that *returns* the transformed type:

```
function transformType(Type: typeof Test) {
    return Test as unknown as TransformedTestConstructor;
}
const TransformedTest = transformType(Test);
```

This will return `Test` as the transformed constructor: but it won't bring `TransformedTest` into scope as a type, like a normal class - it only brings in the constructor (as a value) into scope.  So if `Test` is mutable and you do:

```
Test = transformType(Test);
```

Then the *value* Test will be the new constructor, but the *type* will still be the old instance.

---

[Here's the code from this answer in the Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBYAUNH0AeAhAFzQB2ArgLYBG8ATgNxa7QAOdAlgG5hLzQBPYmSq1GWAL5YsSAa34A5UfQiwA9gGUknUgHMIAHlgA+aAF40zXAG0A0tA6loAa3gC1AMzgBdErDve0PB4fKQAJjAUNPTQAPzQyDq60H4BktKYMnL8AMLgULB0YKQQHmp0lAZWAPIgYXmQMMGhEWTwAO7QABQAdH1gdPokxQLW3gCU5qYjADRWCh2w2VimFrX1+U0h8OGRHd19PQNDDqQeMQCCgxCTZtOkAlbxpPu9-dckV-q3pgvtS-IrCQXlx6ExMhDZPI4EUSmUKvAwghkOZoEponRVJptI59EZEEhjOCofxCsVSuVKIjkUgcmoStpyMAkOVUdAGgVYRSKgYSZ44ASZjDyfCqUiCaZwVgAPTS6AAIQEZDAlFx0CQAAsODBNfwICr+JB1Rr+I5kMVgPwSd0yXDKdSCZN2vxdPAULroOQIOQwCBoKBGtBaBqwFwOOUZXLoO0TXQrSb1dkHDqE2akBbDeFjfweCByKaU-xgPTEkyWXQsMWGcK7QjxSiLDToEbyKRnKQ1O0nEbbdyxTS6Qy6GXylLMFWUcEVawQPwLC9Or3RQ7kF1xuCp5QZ-AengeiyAKqseR0HKQeBrsceVvM8NObQiykAi98ZAkPleGmTDDYXBxpDkHQThNi2bYdl2zYwEu9r1rSJaMsyo7pJgso1n2K5IAATMm0D0iASpgNAub5t0HoTgh5bjJW8FocusHYRYD61pQz5dF+4KobACbFnQcYQKw9JhGq1rtGo5B1NAIaguqahBvwYT0vwlDFD6ID4UQWTQtBdY0gx0AAJIMhmz68tk-Laf2BKYUSQA)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I really appreciate it. I definitely will have a deeper look and fiddle around with your suggestion.

Could you maybe add how my example (code snippet of the test file / describe block || located at the end of my issue description) would look like with your suggestions? It would help me do understand it even better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just writing the line `Test = transformType(Test);` would not work, right? Did I understand this correctly? That's why I would really looking forward seeing my example with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're changing into spy instances. Is that about right?

In any case, I think the simple solution here is to alter the type of component using a mapped type.

Example:

```
type SpyifyFunctions<T> = {
  // If jasmine.Spy can be used with type arguments, you could supply that here, too
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? jasmine.Spy : T[K]
}

describe('ParentComponent', () => {
  let component: SpyifyFunctions<ParentComponent>;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentComponent>;

  /**
   * This function is the "marker" for the custom typescript transformer.
   * With this line the typescript transformer "knows" that it has to adjust the class ParentComponent.
   *
   * I don't know if this is possible but it would be cool if after the function "ttransformer" the type for ParentComponent would be adjusted.
   * With adjusted I mean that e.g. each class property of type number is now reflected as type string (as explained in the issue description above)
   */
  ttransformer(ParentComponent);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ParentComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance; // If necessary, cast here (as SpyifyFunctions<ParentComponent>)
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('test it', () => {
    component.ttransformerTest.and.returnValue('Transformer Test');
    expect(component.ttransformerTest).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

## Edit

This problem requires an understanding of the Type system in TypeScript. At first, it can be a little difficult to understand when coming from other languages.

We need to first recognize that types exist *only* during compilation. They're there in order to tell your IDE or the compiler what things should be. This is to help you by providing errors and giving your IDE intellisense. When the code is actually run, types do not exist at all! A good way to get an idea of this is to go to the typescript playground and look at the output javascript (over on the right panel)

Take a look at [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Click the link above to see how this code is stripped of all type information.

```
type Spy<TFunction> = { fn: TFunction }

class ParentComponent {
    // We assume an external transformer will change ttransformerTest from a method to a property with the shape { fn: (original method function) }
    ttransformerTest(): string { return '' }
    p!: string
}

type SpyifyFunctions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? Spy<T[K]> : T[K]
}

// Here we're specifically telling TypeScript what Type the component is, so that we don't get errors trying to use component.fn
const component = new ParentComponent() as unknown as SpyifyFunctions<ParentComponent>;

component.ttransformerTest.fn() // <-- No errors, because TypeScript recognizes this as the proper type for component
```

One key point that should also help gain some understanding is that **there is no way to update the type assigned to a reference once it's been assigned**.

Bear in mind that the types are walked and assigned *before* transformers are run. Believe it or not, this is good. It would be chaotic otherwise.

With that in mind:

- We now know that transformers won't affect the errors in our IDE or compiler, because they happen after the code is already analyzed.
- Since the JavaScript side is taken care of with the transformers, now we need to find a way to "transform" the actual Type in a way that your IDE can recognize.

Here is one way you can do that with a few helper types. This will probably be the best route to do what you're trying to do, given your use-case.

```
/* ************************************************************************************* */
// type-transformers.ts
/* ************************************************************************************* */

type Spy<TFunction> = { fn: TFunction }

type SpyifyFunctions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? Spy<T[K]> : T[K]
}

export type MakeSpyableClass<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any> = 
  T extends new (...args: infer Args) => any ? 
    new (...args: Args) => SpyifyFunctions<InstanceType<T>> : never;


/* ************************************************************************************* */
// ParentComponent.ts
/* ************************************************************************************* */
import { MakeSpyableClass } from './type-transformers.ts'

// Note that we do not export this class, directly, since we need TS to infer its type before 
// we "transform" it as an export
class ParentComponentClass {
    // We assume an external transformer will change ttransformerTest from a method to a 
    // property with the shape { fn: (original method function) }
    ttransformerTest(): string { return '' }
    p!: string
}

// Here is where we create a new exported reference to the class with a specific type that we 
// assign We cast to unknown first, so TypeScript doesn't complain about the function shapes 
// not matching (remember, it doesn't know about your tranformer)
export const ParentComponent = 
  ParentComponentClass as unknown as MakeSpyableClass<typeof ParentComponentClass>


/* ************************************************************************************* */
// example.ts
/* ************************************************************************************* */
import { ParentComponent } from './ParentComponent.ts'

const component = new ParentComponent();
component.ttransformerTest.fn() // <-- Recognizes type as Spy instance
```

[See it in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBCldO38MU5cLALAChjDAFwE8AHAUwFo8AnAQwDsBnAMwHtKBbEy+gOj3q1AQUwkaLEI0WLIVJgAykQIAeACoAxAK60AxngCWzWgD4wAXjABvMI1oAuMOq26DtMAF8pmGSXmK9jAk0dfUN6VRNzCywwMABtAGkwPVcAaxICZkYHAF17FQTssBIADzwSWgATejAg50MwAH5fZXz47JM8gqwPTCwSolY8fGIfAFlqNIUCagAjABsSAGE56nowlSLS8qqwWhIAdzAACm5T6koAc3p7OgJY7IBKMxNbiLBoh02yyuq9w5OzpdrklaIxOGAAIJAp6mF60AiNd6YGIxP7HU7cc5XexQq4wkxTfyBJwhBhKACSDDwdG0JBUI3CHV2JAAbpwANyeATgcS8vn81AgDDYXAABXO5Twi2YbAGe1oeF4-GwPIFavVIkkmD0ssGljA40milmC2Wq2qbmslBlYAA5NxgN4KDQGCx2JweHxbZ4cGAAHLMMr4AAW1CG+x8FWYu0DmwGlCGeGDemq2hWawANGAKnpKCRdHMCFn6MlaWAI8ySBUHHJ8NHkmDKEk+MNZDMSG6fAJcBWAERUOhMVhsXvNsCrceufqDLBp81gcV5hXS3XyqXp6pRZEo30AdR85o0HEnX04tGoc3wLqH7qb+z0c0v2lDtAuPjwA9dw84KhI9CGjDWmw45gBwSbMNWeDRtQSIomAvpENapAJgi95JiGPj0KGshWDY9hHKwegXMkF6gSQ4HVowJIuE8PRwR+15uhwlC-v+RwPPY-6UMkFz6nmeAaJQri2ra7gfDERAAIScVQPHdD6uAABKcD4KblsGKnlj42h5mGB7Moc04JlWYB5o25RllBGFgHOazlno6EwfQpDaP4ejaK276huGXYiuOaxEa4+42asibRloKS0Mw+yuIwub-sW0b0qQcg6XoRBDFGf60LaQzaDKRArMk44zMwGiJhp1jUfUWHUKQ1TdjGQxsGGz48cceYcGw7aUFmDnZsw2W5WAkXRSVZVDBkglXnQTGcA8fTFPGeWhEMi6SiucqSmYsELhKy4FYYG0bv5YARVFMWnYaJBTCaSwbko3iZHtS5Soda5mmsRhciqQgav9AMwFqvolNQsoLEq3J-YDMMalqOrLfq60Hau22WoBNr2sAyNvajCpKt6vSYPlVI2e923mGiOObUdCrsZyxPk-jDGDnNLF-oqNjsfBuBKGQZBgAASvmzAXLQegAF5-p5p1TCC-40iQQA)

### Cautionary note

It's very likely that your approach could be much simpler. It also may have some bad consequences, so I'm adding a few notes that could help.

- It looks like your class is defined and used *outside of just the test environment*.
- It also appears that you'd like to automatically make all the functions into spies during testing.

If that's the case, it would be bad practice to use a transformer to make all of the functions into spies universally. You wouldn't want to implement jasmine code into something running outside of the test environment.

Instead, a better (and far simpler) approach is to write a function that enumerates the property descriptors of the class instance and make its return type use a mapped type so your tests understand what's going on.

A transformer is much more complex than you'd need, and certainly not a good idea to employ for something you only need during testing.

I see you have `TestBed.createComponent`. Assuming that `createComponent` exists in the test space only this would likely be where I'd put in logic that:

1. Iterate Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors() -> If it's a method or a function, update the object with a Jasmine spy for that method/function
2. The return type of the function should use the mapped type helper

Something like

```
type SpyifyFunctions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? Spy<T[K]> : T[K]
}

createComponent<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(component: T): SpyifyFunctions<InstanceType<T>> {
// Create new component
// Iterate descriptors and replace with spies
// return component
}
```

You wanted the least amount of work - trust me when I tell you, a transformer in almost always not the right route to go.

Comment: Yes, I am changing to spy instances.

`class Test {
   public greet(): string {
      return "Hello";
   }
}`

...will be e.g. changed to...

`class Test {
   public greet = jasmine.createSpy();
}`

Comment: For your suggested line `[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends function ? jasmine.Spy : T[K]` in *SpyifyFunctions* I unfortunately get an error: Cannot find name function. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyhow I like the simplicity of your suggestion. But in the best case I would like to get rid of using a *mapped type*. If it is possible I would like not to touch the type definitions of *component* and *fixture*. They should be both of type `ParentComponent` there. I also would like not to have to do the cast in the *beforeEach*. In the best case I would like to just write `ttransformer(ParentComponent)` and from now on the type is changed. I am thinking at something similar to a *type guard*. I know that this is maybe very unusual but I would like to write as less code as possible.

Comment: But the vision explained in the comment before is probably not possible, right? I do not understand this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61991234/13513418) completely yet. But I would be really excited if writing `ParentComponent = ttransformer(ParentComponent)` would be the only thing that has to be done. That would be the direction I am aiming for. But maybe that's just not possible. That's why I am asking. That I have something similar like a *type guard* in mind explains my idea maybe the best.

Comment: Sorry, it should be Function (capital F). I've corrected it. As for the rest, I'll respond in detail in and edit in my reponse

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for your detailed answer. It really helps me to get a better understanding. I really appreciate the support.

Comment: Regarding your proposed solution: If I understand the provided code snippets correctly it would be necessary to touch the *ParentComponent.ts*, right? With touching I mean changing the “normal” export of the class to your offered solution. Is this correct? If this is the case I am unfortunately not completely satisfied with the solution because I would like having not the need to modify any production code. If I understand your post correctly my vision is simply not realizable then. Because updating the type is just not possible. Did I summarize this correctly?

Comment: Regarding my vision/project: The *TypeScript Transformer* and the *ttransformer* function would be provided by an npm package. The usage of the package is meant to be in a testing environment. Therefore I would like that the user does not have to touch his production code. I would imagine that the user just has to configure the transformer and has to call the mentioned function (ttransformer) with the target class in his test suite. Unfortunately the typings are not correct with this solution. That’s why I was asking if this would be solvable by just calling the function. But it‘s not, right?

Comment: Regarding your cautionary note: The *TypeScript Transformer* can be configured to be just in place for the testing environment. Therefore I see no problem here. Otherwise I would totally agree with you. Regarding your proposed solution in this context: `TestBed.createComponent` is provided by the *Angular* framework. Therefore I would not be able to place logic in there. But anyhow, I am curious about your proposed solution. Would it return a modified instance of the original class? I am asking because the transformer is used to avoid *Duck Typing* in the first place.

Comment: Regarding *Duck Typing* mentioned by myself: *Angular* provides „mechanisms“ (ViewChild) matching by type. Therefore stubbing components with duck typing would not be a good approach for this cases. Otherwise other npm packages like *ng-mocks* would already exist and be a good option. These packages help stubbing unneeded components - https://angular.io/guide/testing#stubbing-unneeded-components. That's why I would like to use the transfomer approach. To basically give the user the option to transform the original component into a stub for a specific test (suite). Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: In that case, you can make a function which returns a new version of the component's prototype and uses the mapped type as a return type.

ie. spyifyComponent(TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)).

Look up class components and that should point you in the right direction. cheers